How can I ensure that a user is using his own phone number in my Android app?
My app communicates between 2 users.
User 'A' sends a statement which is posted on my website aimed at User 'B'. He does this using User B's phone number.
User 'B' now accesses this by submitting his own phone number.
As I understand it, accessing the linenumber of the phone is not allowed for security reasons.
However, I'm worried that anyone can access the message if they know User B's phone number.
The App doesn't need to know the user's phone number, just make sure that the phone is who it says it is.
Is there a way to validate this using Kotlin in Android Studio?

If the phone number should be the identifying feature then a common way to verify it is by sending an SMS with a verification code.

The app is to be used in South Africa where most cannot afford SMS.

The users would only receive the SMS, not send it. I guess that is free even in South Africa. It might still be unaffordable for the service you set up, though, because it would need to send an SMS whenever a new user wants to register.
